# Get rectangle coordinates from a point and a line

Tags: matlab, geometry, coordinates

I have the coordinates of 3 points `[x1,y1]`, `[x2,y2]` and `[x3,y3]` as shown below.

They define the line which is one side of a rectangle, and a point which lies on the parallel/opposite side of the rectangle. I want to get the coordinates of the other two corners.

How can I calculate points `[xa, ya]` and `[xb, yb]` as shown?

[image]

```
clc;
clear;

I = imread('peppers.png'); 
imshow(I);
h = imline;
lineEndPoints = wait(h);

x1 = round(lineEndPoints(1,1),2);
y1 = round(lineEndPoints(1,2),2);
x2 = round(lineEndPoints(2,1),2);
y2 = round(lineEndPoints(2,2),2);
hold on 

[x3, y3] = ginput(1);
plot(x3, y3,'b*');

slope = (y2 - y1)/ (x2 - x1);
slopePerp = -1/slope;
```

Comment: Have you thought about orthogonal projection of your third point on to the line [Distance from reference line at right angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28848406/distance-from-reference-line-at-right-angle/28867384#28867384). once you have the distance and the intersection point you are almost done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the slope between `[x1, y1]` and `[x2, y2]` (`slope`) and the slope for the perpendicular line to `[x3, y3]` (`slopPerp`).

So you have the y-intercept for the line `[x1, y1]` to `[x2, y2]` as

```
% From y=mx+c -> c=y-mx
c = y1 - slope*x1;
```

You can also get the y-intercept of the perpendicular line passing through `[x3, y3]`

```
cPerp = y3 - slopePerp*x3;
```

Then the point where your two black lines meet, let's call it `[x4,y4]` is

```
% Simultaneous equations  
% y = slope*x + c
% y = slopePerp*x + cPerp
% slope*x + c = slopePerp*x + cPerp
% x*(slope - slopePerp) = cPerp - c
x4 = (cPerp - c) / (slope - slopePerp);
y4 = slope*x4 + c;
```

Now all we need is the x and y differences

```
xdiff = x3 - x4; % So x4 + xdiff = x3
ydiff = y3 - y4; % So y4 + xdiff = y3
```

And to add these to our 1 and 2 points

```
xa = x1 + xdiff;
ya = y1 + ydiff;
xb = x2 + xdiff;
yb = y2 + ydiff;
```

[image]

---

Note, with all these repeated actions it would probably be neater to store your `x` and `y` values in arrays rather than as separate variables.

Also, there is no reason to be using `round`, it will only make the result less accurate. If you are rounding because you want to display the values, use `sprintf` or round *as* you display, not before calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Vector approach uses projection of point P3 onto line P1P2 and  works for any rotation of rectangle (note that slope does not exist for axis-aligned rectangle)

```
  P4 = P1 + (P2 - P1) * DotProduct(P3 - P1, P2 - P1) / DotProduct(P2 - P1, P2 - P1)
  Pa = P1 + (P3 - P4)
  Pb = P2 + (P3 - P4)
```